# ¿Porque esto es diferente? (identacion)

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.7

parecen lineas de codigo a simple vista iguales pero cuando las pones en un ide salen resultados diferentes

```
# ¿Cuál es el valor de a?
a = 0
for i in range(10):
    a=a+1
print(a)

# ¿Cuál es el valor de a?
a = 0
for i in range(10):
    a = a + 1
for j in range(10):
    a = a + 1
print(a)

# ¿Cuál es el valor de a?
a = 0
for i in range(10):
    a = a + 1
    for j in range(10):
        a = a + 1
print(a)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En el primer caso el valor de "a" es 10 por que estas haciendo que "i" tome 10 valores, y estas diciendo que cada vez que "i" tome un valor incremente en uno a "a"

En el segundo caso es valor de "a" es 20 por que al igual que se hace en el primer ejemplo estas haciendo que "i" tome 10 valores, e incremente a "a" y le estas agregando a "j" que toma 10 valores y hace lo mismo que el "for" de "i"

En el ultimo caso estas haciendo que por cada valor de "i" va a incrementar en uno a "a" y ademas de eso estas haciendo que "j" incremente a "a" 10 veces por cada valor de "i" por lo que seria 10+(10x10) que su resultado seria 110

La diferencia entre el segundo y el tercer ejemplo es que estas haciendo que por cada valor de "i" incremente en uno a "a" 11 veces

Answer (score 0):

Tomemos tu primer código:

```
a = 0
for i in range(10):
    a=a+1
print(a)
```

Lo que hace es lo siguiente:

- Toma una variable que incialmente vale 0
- Incrementa sumandole 1 a dicha variable
- Como resultado da 10 por que el for va hasta 10
- Somo muestra el 10 por que imprimes la variable a por fuera dle for, entonces te retorna el valor mas reciente, es decir el que resultó de la última iteración que es donde queda 9 + 1 dando 10

Vayamos al segundo código:

```
a = 0
for i in range(10):
    a = a + 1
for j in range(10):
    a = a + 1
print(a)
```

Lo que hace es lo siguiente:

- Toma una variable que inicialmente vale 0
- Le suma 1 hasta que el primer for llega a 10, hasta este punto la a vale 10 pues fue el resultado de las iteraciones que realizó el bucle sumandole 1 por cada vuelta
- Esa misma variable que el primer for nos entregó valiendo 10 la pasamos al segundo ciclo, esta vez le seguirá sumando 1 hasta que el ciclo cuyo limite es 10 se complete
- Por cada vuelta irá al 10 del primer for sumando 1 para que al final nos de 20
- Nuevamente como imprimes la variable al final de los 2 ciclos for y por fuera de su *contexto* te va a dar el acumulado que dicha variable recogio después de pasar por los dos ciclos for
- Es importante notar que ambos for inician al mismo nivel de indentación por lo tanto sus acciones son bloques independientes

**Podemos observar su comportamiento**

Agregando al print de cada for un identificador para ver en que momento se esta generando un valor por cual de los dos ciclos

```
a = 0
for i in range(10):
    a = a + 1
    print("valor de i", a)
for j in range(10):
    a = a + 1
    print("valor de j", a)
```

Que nos daría una salida así:

```
valor de i 1
valor de i 2
valor de i 3
valor de i 4
valor de i 5
valor de i 6
valor de i 7
valor de i 8
valor de i 9
valor de i 10
valor de j 11
valor de j 12
valor de j 13
valor de j 14
valor de j 15
valor de j 16
valor de j 17
valor de j 18
valor de j 19
valor de j 20
```

Para el último caso:

Lo podemos reducir a un escenario mas pequeño para ver su funcionamiento asi:

```
a = 0
for i in range(2):
    a = a + 1
    print("valor de i", a)
    for j in range(2):
        a = a + 1
        print("valor de j", a)
print(a)
```

Donde:

Las iteraciones generarían este comportamiento:

```
valor de i 1
valor de j 2
valor de j 3
valor de i 4
valor de j 5
valor de j 6
```

> Finalmente cuando imprimimos a, para este ejemplo nos daría 6 como resultado final, como recomendación revisa las salidas que coloque para que analices mas sobre el comportamiento tanto del segundo y tercer ejemplo